# How to return an error if there are any uppercase letters in string?

Tags: python

Sorry, this is probably obvious to veterans out there but I simply want to `print ("Please only write in lowercase")` if there are any uppercase letter in the inputted string

i've done:

`if string.islower == false 
print ("Please only write in lowercase")`

But is shows an error :/

```
  File "main.py", line 14
if phrase.islower() == False
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Thank you

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried so far?

Comment: check if str.lowercase is equal to str.

Comment: `if not your_input.islower(): ...`

Comment: You need to call the function: `if not string.islower()`

Comment: Why not just convert to lower `string.lower()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the built in string function [`str.islower()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.islower)

Edit: You're so close! You actually unintentionally referenced the actual function. Just execute it. :) Also, you were missing the manditory `:` colon after your conditional.

```
if not phrase.islower():
    print("Please only write in lowercase")
```

Comment: OMG, thank you  i've been trying for the last half hour and now feel stupid

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to stop the execution of a program while running a script/program you can also check this way:

```py
#with throwing an exception during the execution of a script:
_input = 'This is Your input'
if not _input.islower():
    raise Exception('Program Execution Stopped! Please write in lower case only!')
```

Just in case, be aware that you can create your own Exception like this:

```py
_input = 'This is Your input'
class UpperCaseException(Exception):
    pass

if not _input.islower():
    raise UpperCaseException('Program Execution Stopped! Please write in lower case only!')
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you should just force lowercase vice checking for an error.

```
.lower()
```

that said if you want to check if the input is lower

```
var = raw_input("Please write in only lowercase : ")     
if var.islower() :
    print("yup that is lowercase")
else :
    print("That is not lowercase")
```

Comment: `islower` is a method, not an attribute. So this will not always return the expected output

Comment: I typo'd the parens.  Thanks for the catch.

Comment: Also want to note that you mentioned `.lower()` in your first code block but didn't show how it could be utilized as you did with `.islower()`.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, islower() is a built-in method used for string handling.
The islower() methods returns “True” if all characters in the string are lowercase, Otherwise, It returns “False”.